# Maximal abelian subgroup of general linear groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Thanks for any help or comments.

Is it possible to recognize all maximal abelian subgroups of general linear group on finite field $F$ of order $q$,  $GL_n(F)$.
By maximal abelian I mean if $A$ is maximal abelian and $B$ is abelian such that $A\subseteq B$, then $B=A$.

Comment: It's a good question, you should try to ask it on   MathOverflow (http://mathoverflow.net)

Comment: The maximal subgroups of the general linear group are classified by Aschbacher's theorem, but I'm not sure about the maximal Abelian subgroups.

Comment: Link to MO post: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/200269/maximal-abelian-subgroup-of-general-linear-groups